# How to get value of CDATA from xml?

Tags: xml, xslt, cdata

SO basically i have this node in xml for which i want to extract the value of `CDATA` preserving white spaces and line breaks in xslt. I tried to find the solution but couldn't find any. Any help or suggestions will be welcome. Thanks!!

`CDATA`

```
 <fldtandc>
                <![CDATA[Hi
    dsa
    ad
    
    
    dasad
    
    das
    
    
    dfg
    dg
    
    gdfd]]>

</fldtandc>
```

Comment: Extract it to where? What should be the result?

Comment: Oh sorry i will edit my question. I want my result in xslt.

Comment: The XSLT processor does not know about any CDATA sections in the input XML, it uses an underlying XML parser to construct a tree of nodes in which your `fldtandc` simply has a single text child node which contains the complete string inside of the element. So you can select or process the `fldtandc` element as you can select or process any element, it doesn't matter whether the markup contained a CDATA section or not.